# Using /wp-admin works, using /login gives a 404. Why?

Tags: wp-admin, login, 404-error, wp-login-form

I just did a manual install and tried to login, but was unable to do so using domain.com/login. I got a 404 error. When I used domain.com/wp-admin, no issues. Did I do something wrong or forget to do something?

Comment: @toscho - in WP 3.4 wasn't there was supposed to be a redirect that made /login /dashboard and /admin take you to the sign in page...helgatheviking, I didn't make changes after setting it up... could be that I need to go to the permalinks page to make it work.

Comment: Are you allowed to downvote your own question? I was doing something stupid, which actually bypassed WordPress (homemade maintenance page). When I entered, domain.com/wp-admin...the page came up because I called it directly.  Nevermind

Comment: @helgatheviking - going to the permalinks page was not enough. It worked once I chose a pretty permalink.

Comment: Ray, your question is not as stupid as you think. It really doesn’t make sense that `/login` requires permalinks. And it was an opportunity to share a localized version. :)

Answer (score 3):

`/wp-admin/` is an existing directory, your server just adds the missing `/`.
`/login` is … nothing. The correct name is `/wp-login.php`.

If you have enabled permalinks [it should work](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/19880) though.

To make `/login` *always* work add the following line to your `.htaccess` above the WordPress rules:

```
Redirect Permanent /login /wp-login.php
```

You can and *should* localize it if you use other languages:

```
# login in German
Redirect Permanent /anmelden /wp-login.php
```

Answer (score 0):

/login is not a valid url unless you have edited your .htaccess to redirect it correctly.

perhaps you are looking for /wp-login.php